# Mulesoft: How can I get the properties of the customized Business Exception in Catch Exception Strategy

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I'm new to Mulesoft, now I have a question that want to consult here.

I have a customized Exception class defined as below:

```
class IllegalInputException extends Exception {

    private String reasonCode;

    public IllegalInputException (String reasonCode) {
        super();
        this.reasonCode = reasonCode;
    }

    public String getReasonCode() {
        return reasonCode;
    }

    public void setReasonCode(String reasonCode) {
        this.reasonCode = reasonCode;
    }
}
```

The flow will check the input, if it's invalid then will throw the exception.

My question is how I can get the value of reasonCode of the IllegalInputException in the flow of Catch Exception Strategy?

Many thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Within an exception strategy you should be able to access the "exception payload" so an expression like `#[message.exceptionPayload.exception.reasonCode]` should provide what you need.
HTH